# Using Word's Open File Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, vba, vsto, addin-express

I want to use built-in Open File dialog from my VSTO add-in. I have to set [InitialFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210656%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) when showing the dialog. Unfortunately, this property does not exist in the Dialog class:

```
var Dlg = Word.Dialogs.Item(WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileOpen);
Dlg.InitialFileName = SomePath; //COMPILE ERROR: no such property
```

Try to cast it to `FileDialog` also doesn't work:

```
var Dlg = Word.Dialogs.Item(WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileOpen) as FileDialog;
Dlg.InitialFileName = SomePath; //RUNTIME EXCEPTION: null reference
```

What am I missing here?

Note: I'm using Add-in Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I had to cast my application object to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` to get access to the `FileDialog` member. The following code works:

```
var Dlg = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)Word).get_FileDialog(MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFilePicker);
Dlg.InitialFileName = STRfolderroot + STRfoldertemplatescommon + "\\" + TheModality + "\\" + TheModality + " " + TheStudyType + "\\";
Dlg.Show();
```

Comment: Nice one! Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft page in your post shows the property being used for the `msoFileDialogFilePicker` dialog but your code is using the `wdDialogFileOpen`. The example code on the MS page works fine but trying to use the property for `wdDialogFileOpen` also generates a run-time error.

So this works:

```
Sub ThisWorks()

    Dim fd As FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "C:\folder\printer_ink_test.docx"

        'If the user presses the action button...
        If .Show = -1 Then

            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                MsgBox "Selected item's path: " & vrtSelectedItem
            Next vrtSelectedItem
        'If the user presses Cancel...
        Else
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

But this fails:

```
Sub ThisFails()

    Dim fd As Dialog

    Set fd = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)

    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    With fd
        ' This line causes a run-time error
        .InitialFileName = "C:\folder\printer_ink_test.docx"

        'If the user presses the action button...
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                MsgBox "Selected item's path: " & vrtSelectedItem
            Next vrtSelectedItem
        'If the user presses Cancel...
        Else
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I do not see `FileDialog` as an option anywhere in VSTO. Note that unlike the MSDN page, I'm not using VBA.

Comment: The article tells that I should be using `get_FileDialog()` method in C#, but even that does not exist in `Application` class. I'm using Add-in Express if that is playing some part here.

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry for screenshot, I'm using my phone to answer.*

This is how you do it for Excel according to the picture from google books: `Globals.ThisWorkbook.ThisApplication.FileDialog`

[image]

For MS Word according to this [link](http://www.codemag.com/Article/090153), this is how its done:

```
Office.FileDialog dialog = app.get_FileDialog(
  Office.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFilePicker);
//dialog.InitialFileName  <-- set initial file name
dialog.Show();
```